# Chrome не опознаёт загруженные стили

Tags: css, google-chrome, mime

Решил я для общего развития сделать анонимайзер. Чтобы все ссылки проходили через него, я сделал замену абсолютно всех ссылок(и локальных, и глобальных) на те, которые бы проходили через анонимайзер (т.е. `href="http://2ip.ru"` заменялось на `href="http://%адрес_анонимайзера%/?link=http://2ip.ru")`. С заменой адресов ссылок проблем не наступило, но до такой замены сайты выглядели так: [image: До замены ссылок]

А после стали выглядеть вот так:
[image: После замены]

При этом, в консоль вывелись сообщения с одинаковым текстом про загрузку стилей:
`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html`
Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, что тут надо делать?
[image]
Вкладка network:

Comment: На всякий случай, ваш анонимайзер передаёт заголовки вместе с контентом? Как выглядит файл стилей в веб-инспекторе (во вкладке Network)?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос. Интересно, что там он опознан как stylesheet.

Comment: А заголовки-то передаются? Содержимое CSS-файла в точности такое же? Странно всё это, конечно.